# How can you use the load method of jquery tabs to load multiple tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

As far as I'm aware, the jQuery tabs load method handles only a single tab index, as below :

```
.tabs( "load" , index )
```

Trying multiple calls in succession only cancels the earlier calls i.e.:

```
.tabs ("load", 2)

.tabs ("load", 3)
```

The load of tabindex 2 is cancelled by the subsequent load of tabindex 3.

How can you call the load method without the earlier calls being cancelled by the later calls?

Comment: Can you please give a bit more detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you trying to preload the content that's in gets loaded in the tabs?

Comment: @westo : My application requires two tabs to be reloaded frequently when some fields on other tabs are edited.

Comment: @JaredFarrish : No, I'm not trying to preload these tabs. I'm just trying to load them using the load method. I do not need them preloaded. However , I do need to reload two tabs frequently when some other fields on the page are updated.

Comment: You can access all of the content on the tabs from javascript without reloading. Tabs are essentially DIVs. If you really need to "reload" as in make another AJAX call to the server then you could do this when the tab is selected.

Comment: @westo . Thanks. I just thought it would be cleaner to use the load method rather than access a div manually and reload.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it. I use a method like this with some AJAX functionality to do sleek adding of tabs on the fly.

```
$("#nameOfMyTabsList").tabs("add", "#href-to-my-element"+some_unique_string, "This Is The Link Text!");
```

This will create the tab, and a div with the id of:

```
<div id="href-to-my-element">
  //this is where my text is.
</div>
```

The ajax:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'location/to/my/file.php',
 data: 'data='+myDataVar,
 success: function(data){
   $("#nameOfMyTabsList").tabs("add", "#href-to-my-element"+some_unique_string, "This Is The Link Text!");
   $("#href-to-my-element"+some_unique_string).html(data);
 }
});
```

Alright..we're almost there, but how did I create dynamic divs that are unique? Well, here we go:

```
$("#whatever").click(function(){
  //I had a list of elements, each one had it's own unique name, so I created a variable from my links text when I click.
  var ourTabName = $(this).text;
  //I did some regexp and replacing of unwanted values so there wasn't issues with &, -, and / operators
  var cleanTabName = ourTabName(//do regexp);
  //the data I needed to send to the server is held in my HREF tag. A replace of the hash tag and I'm good to go
  var myDataVar = $(this).attr("href");
  //just a simple removal, nothing fancy
  var myDataVar = myDataVar.replace(/#/g, '');
  //now I can do my ajax. all my variables are set. let's build the new tabs and inject the content.
  $.ajax({
    url: 'location/to/my/file.php',
    data: 'data='+myDataVar,
    success: function(data){
       //This is where pure magic happens. See our cleanName? we're using it again for the dynamic ID tags and Links so we don't run into any issues.
      $("#nameOfMyTabsList").tabs("add", "#href-to-my-element"+cleanTabName, "This Is The Link Text!");
      //now that the link and div have been created, we access the div with the same identifer we just made in the above line. then we append the data that was returned from our ajax request.
      $("#href-to-my-element"+some_unique-string).html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

This is the solution that I used to create dynamic tabs. I'm not saying it's pretty (by any means); but it's a 100% tested and verified solution.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be code for adding new tabs. I do not want to add any tabs, I simply need to reload (or refresh) some tabs using the load method. The scenario is : I have 8 tabs that are linked to some AJAX content. I want to reload tabindex 2 and 3 (regardless of whether they were previously loaded or not). Hope this info helps.

Comment: So what you're really saying is that you need to make the $.ajax calls for Tab2 and Tab3 into functions, and call those functions when you invoke events that require reloading of those tabs? Let me see yarrrr Ajax calls. I'll give yee a hand.

Comment: Thanks. Here is what I'm trying to achieve. I have an AJAX call to a remote resource that returns (among other things) an array of tab indices. I then loop through this array and "load" these tabs. But what is happening with the load method is that the browser cancels the first load when it moves to the second load and so on.           for(i=0; i<tabsToLoad.length; i++)
      {
      $('#tabs').tabs("load",tabsToLoad[i]);
      }

Comment: @ivaman - When you call `$mytabs.tab('load', index)`, you're actually requesting UI to reload the content according to what it's set to load from the link in the tab. Why not use IDs, reference which element needs to be updated by the ID you return in your response, and then `$('#respID').html()` to update it's contents? They're still elements on the page which can be accessed like any other.

Comment: @JaredFarrish : Thanks. I just thought its doable with the load method. I just figured it would be a cleaner way to do it. But if that is the only way to achieve this, then I will be going down that path. Thanks again.